# How to Cbind a data.table and a vector

Tags: r, data.table

I want to cbind a data.table and a vector in such a way that the vector contents becomes new columns for the data.table with zero values.

```
DT <- data.table(x=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), y = rnorm(6))

DT2 <- c("paper11grid1", "paper12grid1", "paper13grid1")
```

I want to to update the contents of DT2 as new coumnnames of DT

```
 x          y     paper11grid1 paper12grid1 paper13grid1

 A  0.9643131           0   0   0

 B -0.8856350           0   0   0

 C -0.1489705           0   0   0

 D  2.0675105           0   0   0

 E -1.2965938           0   0   0

 F -0.8468514           0   0   0
```

A cbind directly will just add the DT2 as one coumn

```
cbind(DT, DT2)
```

Comment: Btw, `cbind` is for creating a new table, but you want to "update...DT", which is why you'll want to use := as in Matt's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `data.table`, you can assign values to multiple columns specified in a vector. With that approach, your answer is as simple as the following:

```
DT[,(DT2) := 0]
```

One distinction to note: even though `DT2` is a valid vector, `DT[, DT2 := 0]` will simply result in a single new column named `DT2`. This has to do with the way that column names are evaluated within `[...]`. By using parenthesis -- `(DT2)` -- within the brackets, `[.data.table` will evaluate `DT2` as a vector in this case, not a column name.

Comment: Parentheses are enough without `c`

Comment: Thanks @Frank -- it seems I've always got a little bit more to learn from you. Looking at the source for `[.data.table` now, do parenthesis always trigger an attempt to evaluate the contents in the parent environment first, or is it a little more nuanced than that?

Comment: I think it looks at `\`:=\`(lhs, rhs)` and checks if `lhs` is a symbol. If not, it evals it and looks for a vector of column names or positions.